# Android cryptography library FIPS validation

Tags: android, cryptography, fips, javax.crypto

I want to know, is the android's cryptography library (`javax.crypto`) "[validated to FIPS 140-2](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/140val-all.htm)"?

I need for a specific product which FIPS is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `javax.crypto` is not FIPS-validated, you'll need another lib for that.

However, it is impossible to reach level 2 with libraries alone, as it has requirements
on the hardware too (and a typical Android device is not validated either).

Comment: Yes, I just need FIPS 140-2 level1(without physical security mechanisms).